# NSMenuItem and NSPopOver

Tags: cocoa, popover, nsmenuitem

On OS X app, what is the technique to show a NSPopover when the mouse is over a NSMenuItem (like in spotlight for example).

Thanks a lot!!!
Christopjhe

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a while, but if you still haven't found a solution:

Register your class as a `NSMenuDelegate` to the menu that contains the `NSMenuItem`, and implement

```
- (void)menu:(NSMenu *)menu willHighlightItem:(NSMenuItem *)item;
```

then show the popover when this method is called.

Comment: and how do I point the popover to the menu item if NSMenuItem has no bounds and no view? I am new to OSX development. If you can show some code I appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Can you show your code in the question? It would make it easier to help you. But without knowing what your code looks like, this might work for you:

Add this to your statusItem

```
self.statusItem.action = @selector(clickStatusBar:);
```

Add method similar to this to make the popover appear

```
- (void)clickStatusBar:(id)sender {
    [[self popover] showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
}
```

Comment: I do not have any code to show since I do not know how to do code that ;) But thanks for the answer, I will try this and if ti works I will update for some mouse over instead of click.

Comment: @ChristopheHAMERLING Here are two tutorial videos that can help you get started:  Create A MenuBar Application - http://youtu.be/HRPMFNDcfLY  Create an NSPopover - http://youtu.be/P3uehLU67cg

Comment: this will not work because sender will be a NSMenuItem and NSMenuItems have no bounds. This will crash.

Comment: @Gavin - excuse my ignorance but I am extremely new to development on OSX (~2 weeks and struggling) but you say "add this to your statusitem"... what is that? where do I add this? At this time all I have is a menu on interface builder linked to an action on a class. Thanks.