# Calling popover from a menu item

Tags: objective-c, osx-mavericks

I am new to cocoa language.My Requirement :
Popover should open on click of menu item.I have created menu item dynamically.

1.

```
NSMenu *theMenu =[[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contextual Menu"];
        [theMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Insert Comments" action:@selector(insertComments:) keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:0];
```

2.

```
- (IBAction)insertComments:(id)sender
{

    [self.popover showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMaxXEdge];

}
```

I getting this error `-[NSMenuItem bounds]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000ebdee0` 
What should be the send to showRelativeToRect for MenuItem.

Comment: You didn't read the comments from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149675/nsmenuitem-and-nspopover) you took this code from did you?

Comment: Are you sure you want a `NSPopover` ? Aren't `NSPopupButton` better for what you intend to do ? Have a look at Apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/HowMenusWork.html) and sample code (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/MenuMadness/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008870)

Comment: Requirement for my enhancement :On click of each sell in table view

Comment: No I haven,t took the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149675/nsmenuitem-and-nspopover . My exact requirement is insert comment functionality of excel sheet.This function functionality i have to implement in each cell of my table view.Table view created in my code is dynamic.