# Putting a window in main menu xCode

Tags: xcode, cocoa

Is there a way to place a window in the main Menu on xCode?

Also, is there a decent way for a beginner to learn objective C to create a User Interface?

Comment: You can use NSPopOver for this. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149675/nsmenuitem-and-nspopover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't put windows on menus, in Cocoa. But you are certainly talking about a "view", which is a general container for subviews, buttons, images and alike.